# Obtain a crash message-App keeps stopping

Tags: kotlin

I get the following trace error java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.myhouse.MainActivity cannot be cast to com.brsthegck.kanbanboard.TasklistFragment$Callbacks at com.brsthegck.kanbanboard.TasklistFragment.onAttach(TasklistFragment.kt:52)at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performAttach(Fragment.java:2672) at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.attach(FragmentStateManager.java:263) at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1170) at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1356)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5pps.png)

1. Tasklist Fragment

   ```
      private const val ARG_TASKLIST_TYPE = "tasklist_type"
        private const val TASKLIST_TYPE_TODO = 0
        private const val TASKLIST_TYPE_DOING = 1
        private const val TASKLIST_TYPE_DONE = 2
        class TasklistFragment : Fragment(){
            private lateinit var visibleColorPaletteViewList : List<View>
            lateinit var taskRecyclerView: RecyclerView
            private var tasklistType : Int = -1
            private var adapter : TaskViewAdapter? = TaskViewAdapter(LinkedList<Task>())
            private var colorPaletteIsVisible : Boolean = false
            private var callbacks: Callbacks? = null
            //Callback interface to delegate access functions in MainActivity
            interface Callbacks{
                fun addTaskToViewModel(task: Task, destinationTasklistType: Int)
                fun deleteTaskFromViewModel(tasklistType: Int, adapterPosition: Int)
                fun getTaskListFromViewModel(tasklistType: Int) : LinkedList<Task>

            }

            //Attach context as a Callbacks reference to the callbacks variable when fragment attaches to container
            override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
                super.onAttach(context)
                callbacks = activity as Callbacks? // error is here
            }

            //Detach context (assign to null) when fragment detaches from container
            override fun onDetach() {
                super.onDetach()
                callbacks = null
            }

            //ItemTouchHelper instance with custom callback, to move task card view positions on hold
            private val itemTouchHelper by lazy{
                val taskItemTouchCallback = object : ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(UP or DOWN, 0){
                    override fun onMove(recyclerView: RecyclerView,
                                        viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
                                        target: RecyclerView.ViewHolder): Boolean {
                        val adapter = recyclerView.adapter as TaskViewAdapter
                        val from = viewHolder.adapterPosition
                        val to = target.adapterPosition

                        adapter.moveTaskView(from, to)
                        adapter.notifyItemMoved(from, to)

                        return true
                    }

                    //Make taskview transparent while being moved
                    override fun onSelectedChanged(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder?, actionState: Int) {
                        super.onSelectedChanged(viewHolder, actionState)

                        if(actionState == ACTION_STATE_DRAG)
                            viewHolder?.itemView?.alpha = 0.7f
                    }

                    //Make taskview opaque while being
                    override fun clearView(recyclerView: RecyclerView, viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder) {
                        super.clearView(recyclerView, viewHolder)

                        viewHolder.itemView.alpha = 1.0f
                    }
                    override fun onSwiped(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, direction: Int) { /* Not implemented on purpose. */ }
                }
                ItemTouchHelper(taskItemTouchCallback)
            }

            //Get the fragment arguments, tasklist type to be precise, and assign it to the member of this fragment
            override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
                tasklistType = arguments?.getInt(ARG_TASKLIST_TYPE) as Int
            }

            //Inflate view of fragment, prepare recycler view and it's layout manager, and update the UI
            override fun onCreateView(
                    inflater: LayoutInflater,
                    container: ViewGroup?,
                    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
            ): View?{
                //Inflate the layout of this fragment, get recyclerview ref, set layout manager for recycler view
                val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tasklist_fragment_layout, container,false)
                taskRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.task_recycler_view) as RecyclerView
                taskRecyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
                itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(taskRecyclerView)

                //Fill the recyclerview with data from viewmodel
                updateInterface()

                //Return the created view
                return view
            }

            //Populate recyclerview and set up its adapter
            private fun updateInterface(){
                val tasks = callbacks!!.getTaskListFromViewModel(tasklistType)
                adapter = TaskViewAdapter(tasks)
                taskRecyclerView.adapter = adapter
            }
   ```

   2. Kanban class

   class Kanban : Fragment(), TasklistFragment.Callbacks{
   // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
   private var param1: String? = null
   private var param2: String? = null
   private lateinit var viewPager: ViewPager2
   private lateinit var tabLayout: TabLayout
   private lateinit var taskViewModel: TaskViewModel
   //When add action bar button is pressed
   override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem) = when(item.itemId) {
   R.id.action_new_task -> {
   val currentTasklistType = viewPager.currentItem

   ```
                val currentTasklist = when (currentTasklistType) {
                    TASKLIST_TYPE_TODO -> taskViewModel.todoTaskList
                    TASKLIST_TYPE_DOING -> taskViewModel.doingTaskList
                    TASKLIST_TYPE_DONE -> taskViewModel.doneTaskList
                    else -> throw Exception("Unrecognized tasklist type")
                }
                val currentFragment = (activity?.supportFragmentManager?.fragments?.get(currentTasklistType) as TasklistFragment)

                addTaskToViewModel(Task(), currentTasklistType)

                currentFragment.taskRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(currentTasklist.size - 1)
                true
            }
            else -> super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
        //Inflate the action bar menu resource on options menu creation
        override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_action_bar, menu)
        }

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            arguments?.let {
                param1 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
                param2 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM2)
            }

        }

        override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
        ): View? {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            //Get viewmodel

            val view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_kanban2, container, false)

            taskViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(TaskViewModel::class.java)

            //Read tasklist data from shared prefs and populate viewmodel lists with it
            readSharedPrefsToViewModel()

            //Get ref to viewpager and set up its adapter & attributes
            viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.view_pager)
            val viewPagerAdapter = TasklistFragmentStateAdapter(this)
            viewPager.apply {
                adapter = viewPagerAdapter
                offscreenPageLimit = 2
                //Get ref to tablayout, set up & attach its mediator
                tabLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout)
                TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager) { tab, position ->
                    tab.text = when (position) {
                        0 -> getString(R.string.tab_label_todo)
                        1 -> getString(R.string.tab_label_doing)
                        else -> getString(R.string.tab_label_done)
                    }
                }.attach()
            }
            return view
        }
        override fun onStop() {
            super.onStop()
            writeViewModelToSharedPrefs()
        }

        //Adapter class for view pager
        private inner class TasklistFragmentStateAdapter(fa: Kanban) : FragmentStateAdapter(fa){
            override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
                //Create argument bundle with task list type
                val tasklistFragmentArguments = Bundle().apply{
                    putInt(ARG_TASKLIST_TYPE, position)
                }

                //Attach the argument bundle to new fragment instance and return the fragment
                return TasklistFragment().apply{
                    arguments = tasklistFragmentArguments
                }
            }

            override fun getItemCount(): Int = NUM_TASKLIST_PAGES
        }

        override fun addTaskToViewModel(task: Task, destinationTasklistType: Int) {
            val destinationFragment = (activity?.supportFragmentManager?.fragments?.get(destinationTasklistType) as TasklistFragment)
            val taskList = getTaskListFromViewModel(destinationTasklistType)
            taskList.add(task)
            destinationFragment.taskRecyclerView.adapter?.notifyItemInserted(taskList.size)
        }

        override fun deleteTaskFromViewModel(tasklistType: Int, adapterPosition: Int) {
            val tasklistFragment = (activity?.supportFragmentManager?.fragments?.get(tasklistType) as TasklistFragment)
            getTaskListFromViewModel(tasklistType).removeAt(adapterPosition)
            tasklistFragment.taskRecyclerView.adapter?.notifyItemRemoved(adapterPosition)
        }

        override fun getTaskListFromViewModel(tasklistType: Int): LinkedList<Task> =
        when(tasklistType){
            TASKLIST_TYPE_TODO -> taskViewModel.todoTaskList
            TASKLIST_TYPE_DOING -> taskViewModel.doingTaskList
            TASKLIST_TYPE_DONE -> taskViewModel.doneTaskList
            else -> throw Exception("Unrecognized tasklist type") }
        private fun writeViewModelToSharedPrefs(){
            val gson = Gson()

            //Convert list to json string
            val todoJSON = gson.toJson(taskViewModel.todoTaskList)
            val doingJSON = gson.toJson(taskViewModel.doingTaskList)
            val doneJSON = gson.toJson(taskViewModel.doneTaskList)
            var sharedPref : SharedPreferences = requireActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            //Save json strings into shared preferences
            activity?.getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE)?.edit()?.apply {
                putString(KEY_TODO_JSON, todoJSON)
                putString(KEY_DOING_JSON, doingJSON)
                putString(KEY_DONE_JSON, doneJSON)
            }?.apply()
        }
        private fun readSharedPrefsToViewModel(){
            val gson = Gson()
            val sharedPrefs = activity?.getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE)

            val todoJSON = sharedPrefs?.getString(KEY_TODO_JSON, "[]")
            val doingJSON = sharedPrefs?.getString(KEY_DOING_JSON, "[]")
            val doneJSON = sharedPrefs?.getString(KEY_DONE_JSON, "[]")

            val type = object: TypeToken<LinkedList<Task>>() {}.type //Gson requires type ref for generic types
            taskViewModel.todoTaskList = gson.fromJson(todoJSON, type)
            taskViewModel.doingTaskList = gson.fromJson(doingJSON, type)
            taskViewModel.doneTaskList = gson.fromJson(doneJSON, type)
        }
   ```

   3. Main activity

      ```
       public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


               private TabLayout tabLayout;
               private ViewPager2 viewPager2;
               private MyFragment adapter;
               private TextView register;
               GridView contractorsGV;
               @Override
               protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                   tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
                   viewPager2 = findViewById(R.id.viewPager2);
                   tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Home"));
                   tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Idea Book"));
                   tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("My Profile"));

                   FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                   adapter = new MyFragment(fragmentManager , getLifecycle());
                   viewPager2.setAdapter(adapter);


       4. Fragment manager
      ```

   public class MyFragment extends FragmentStateAdapter {

   ```
            public MyFragment(@NonNull FragmentManager fm,Lifecycle lifecycle) {
                super(fm,lifecycle);
            }

            @NonNull
            @Override
            public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
                if(position==1)
                {
                    return new Kanban();
                }
                if(position==2) {
                    return new signOut();
                }
                    return new Navigation_Bar();
            }
   ```

Comment: Does ``MainActivity`` implement ``Callbacks``? Why's the interface declared inside your Fragment if it's something an Activity can implement?

Comment: ive added the app archictecture

Comment: Yeah see, ``MainActivity`` doesn't say ``implements Callbacks``, so it isn't a ``Callbacks`` and you can't cast it to one with ``as``

Comment: what do i need to do then

Comment: Make ``MainActivity`` implement ``Callbacks`` and provide an implementation of all the methods in the interface. This is fundamental Java/Kotlin stuff, so honestly if you're not familiar with it, you should probably read some basic language tutorials first. But like I said in the other question you posted, all your interface method names relate to a ``ViewModel``, so you should probably access that directly in the ``Fragment`` instead of trying to do it indirectly through an interface on your ``Activity``